# How to build with module path in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, module-path

Currently when I build my Java programs in Netbeans it asks for a classpath and wants to build with a classpath. However, keeping with the growing modular focus of Java 9+ I would rather compile with a module path.

I would run the command `javac ... --module-path *.java` but have complex dependencies and so would prefer to build it in Netbeans if there is that option available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Select your project in the **Projects** panel
- Right click and select **Properties** from the context menu.
- Select **Libraries** from the list of **Categories**
- Click the various tabs (*Compile*, *Run*, etc...) to set **ModulePath** as required.